# how to setup snowplow html5 media tracking using GTM

Tags: google-tag-manager, snowplow

am trying to set up a html5 media tracking in GTM
I am using a javascript tracker version 3.9.0

this is the doc link for the Html5 media tracker
https://docs.snowplow.io/docs/collecting-data/collecting-from-own-applications/javascript-trackers/javascript-tracker/javascript-tracker-v3/plugins/media-tracking/#capturable-events

Plugin URL https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@snowplow/browser-plugin-media-tracking@latest/dist/index.umd.min.js

I need to getcontextlike below

```
 {
    "htmlId": "my-video",
    "mediaType": "VIDEO",
    "autoPlay": false,
    "buffered": [
        {
            "start": 0, "end" : 20
        }
    ],
    "controls": true,
    "currentSrc": "http://example.com/video.mp4",
    "defaultMuted": true,
    "defaultPlaybackRate": 1,
    "disableRemotePlayback": false,
    "error": null,
    "networkState": "IDLE",
    "preload": "metadata",
    "readyState": "ENOUGH_DATA",
    "seekable": [
        {
            "start": 0, "end" : 20
        }
    ],
    "seeking": false,
    "src": "http://example.com/video.mp4",
    "textTracks": [
        {
            "label": "English",
            "language": "en",
            "kind": "captions",
            "mode": "showing",
        },
    ],
    "fileExtension": "mp4",
    "fullscreen": false,
    "pictureInPicture": false
}
```